# MATLAB: Load files from folder by extension

Tags: matlab, filesystems

What is the easiest way to load all files from a folder with the same extension into MATLAB?

Previous solutions by me:

```
%%% Will load a file if its filename is provided
%%% USAGE: (Best save data to a variable to work with it.)
%%% >> x = loadwrapper('<file_name>')
%%% ... and then use 'x' all the way you want.
%%% <file_name> works with absolute and relative paths, too.

function [ loaded_data ] = loadwrapper( file_name )

    files = dir(file_name);
    loaded_data = load(files.name);

end
```

and

```
%%% put this in a new script, in a function it WILL NOT WORK!
%%% and fix your paths, ofc. i left mine in here on purpose.


%%% SETTINGS
folderName='/home/user/folder/';
extension='*.dat';


%%% CODE
concattedString=strcat(folderName, extension);
fileSet=dir(concattedString); 

% loop from 1 through to the amount of rows
for i = 1:length(fileSet)

    % load file with absolute path, 
    % the fileSet provides just the single filename
    load (strcat(folderName, fileSet(i).name)); 

end


%%% TIDY UP
%%% only imported files shall stay in workspace area
clear folderName;
clear extension;
clear concattedString;
clear fileSet;
clear i;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `dir` to get all desired files. Then you can iterate over them with a for loop and call `load` for each. For example, the following:

```
files = dir('C:\myfolder\*.txt');
for k = 1:length(files)
    load(files(k).name, '-ascii')
end
```

loads all files in "C:\myfolder" with the extension "txt".

Comment: while you are at it, if you call this function from folder other than `'c:\myfolder'` and `'c:\myfolder'` is not in your path, you'll have to use `load( fullfile( 'c:\myfolder', files(k).name ), '-ascii' );`

Comment: @Shai Again, you're right. However, I gave this as an example just to accompany my suggestion of using the `dir` command, not a full-blown tutorial about working with files in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import all the functions from a directory, you can use addpath :

In matlab you are in the c:\matlab\work directory and you tap :

```
addpath directory_where_all_my_functions_are
```

to import all the function of the `c:\matlab\work\directory_where_all_my_function_are`

`help addpath` in matlab for more information