# Cycling through a folder and using a matlab operation on each file

Tags: file, matlab, function, directory

I am BRAND NEW to Matlab (like, 5-minutes ago new).  I need it to read some files that I have because no other program can read them.  I was hoping someone could help me understand some basic matlab so that I can accomplish this.  I need to go through every file in a folder and perform the function

```
X = multibandread(filename, size, precision, offset, interleave, byte order)
```

on each file. (X is an array and I need to make a different array for each file).  To further complicate things, the size argument to multibandread is a 3-element vector of [height, width,N], and I'd like to get the height and width values from other files.  i.e:
[size(other_file, 1) size(other_file, 2) 2].

So, I'm still very much trying to understand matlab.  It seems like a powerful type of command prompt that I can write programs into? Is that accurate?  Is there a way to point to each file in my program, call multibandread on it, and then move to the next file?
I know some C programming but know absolutely nothing about matlab.

Thanks for any help or really any general matlab education anyone can give!

Comment: related question: [Load files from folder by extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811683/). Just choose a different operation instead of `load`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the inbuilt Matlab `dir` command and a simple loop:

```
myFiles = dir('c:\MyFolder');
% Now loop through the files.
for k = 1:numel(myFiles)
    X = multibandread(myFiles(k).name, size, precision, offset, interleave, byte order);
end
```